# XSD : How to check that only last element contains attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I have an XML document :

```
<Feature> 
    <Filter> ... </Filter>
    <Filter> ... </Filter>
    <Filter isTargetFilter="true"> ... </Filter>
</Feature>
```

Feature can hold max 3 Filter elements.

Using XSD I want to check that only last Filter element will contain an attribute "isTargetFilter".

No other Filter element can contain this attribute.

I did not find any XSD expression that can help me.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You probably do not have control over the XML format, but this is not a very well-designed format. Surely it would be simpler to add an optional tag after the list of 'Filter' tags to hold this information?

Comment: @kimbert : That is one probable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD (both 1.0 and 1.1), if two elements are siblings and have the same name, then they must have the same type. (The constraint is called *Element Declarations Consistent*, if you want to look it up).

So the only way to do this is with XSD 1.1 assertions. Define assertions on the Feature element:

```
<xs:assert test="every $f in Filter[not(position()=last())] satisfies empty(@isTargetFilter)"/>
<xs:assert test="Filter[position()=last()][@isTargetFilter]"/>
```